# Android N update: strange icon

Tags: 7.0-nougat, notification-bar, notification-icons

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S6 edge and yesterday I updated it to Android 7.0.
It's really easy to use and I really like it. 
But I have a question: In the notification bar there is an icon that I never seen before.

Here is the screen:

[image]

I know it's a stupid question but please, I've got to understand what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That symbol represents that the data saver is on.

Data saver prevents apps from using data in the background (when you are on a mobile network, not WiFi), saving you mobile data and battery. Go to quick settings and toggle the data saver switch if you want to turn it off.

Comment: samsung galaxy s6 edge android 7.0 setting...
connections...
data usage...
data saver... off